# Permission access to php page

Tags: php, apache

I have website on one host(host A) and another website which I include with `iframe`(on host B).

From that `iframe` I would like to go to one of my pages from my host A, but I get this error

> You don't have permission to access
>   /pages/online.php on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error
>   was encountered while trying to use an
>   ErrorDocument to handle the request.

How can I fix that? It worked good when I was using another server.

Apache error logs:

```
[Fri Jul 01 03:24:37 2011] [error] [client some-ip-here] File does not exist: /home/etcorg/public_html/proba/500.shtml, referer: proba.etc.org.rs/pages [Fri Jul 01 03:24:37 2011] [error] [client x.x.x.x] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/etcorg/public_html/proba/pages/online.php" is writeable by group, referer: somepage.com
```

Comment: are you sure the iframe link is correct?

Comment: yes. also when I try to reach my .php page I can't access directly to the page. I get this error
"
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@proba.etc.org.rs and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: then it has nothing to do with the iframe. Do you have access to apache logs?

Comment: I am not sure where on hosting are apache logs?

Comment: if you have ssh shell access then its (usually) /var/log/apache2 or something similar, but they could be set for a virtual host separately

Comment: I found it through cpanel

this is what i got there

[Fri Jul 01 03:24:37 2011] [error] [client 89.216.181.253] File does not exist: /home/etcorg/public_html/proba/500.shtml, referer: http://proba.etc.org.rs/pages/
[Fri Jul 01 03:24:37 2011] [error] [client 89.216.181.253] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/etcorg/public_html/proba/pages/online.php" is writeable by group, referer: http://proba.etc.org.rs/pages/

Comment: Searching for your error message showed magento forum's with people saying that setting 644 rights for for the index.php. Maybe magento does not want it to have 777 (and it sure isn't a best practice either).

Comment: I fixed the problem. It should be 755. Thanks everyone for help

Answer (score 1):

I think your host has program that checks that the permissions aren't set too high (over 644). Thus the error. Change all the rights to 644 for files and 755 for directories.

Comment: now I can open direct page
but I can't open it using iframe, and with parameter. 
I get error 403
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /pages/online.php on this server.

Comment: well, what are the new errors in the errors file, please post your .htaccess as well or try renaming it for a test to .htaccess.test to see if it's the problem?

Comment: well, I can open page directly: 
http://proba.etc.org.rs/pages/online.php
but can't if it goes with parameter
http://proba.etc.org.rs/pages/online.php?URLValue=http%3A//test.prijava.etc.org.rs/dobrodosli.aspx%3FETCCodeCharacter%3DI

it said it's forbidden

Comment: any why aren't you including the iframe like this: <iframe src="http://test.prijava.etc.org.rs/dobrodosli.aspx?ETCCodeCharacter=I"></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

Check the reading rights on this file on the server for Apache user.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use full URL in your iframe (ex: http://www.SiteB.com/pages/online.php)

Answer (score 0):

The error

> You don't have permission to access /pages/online.php on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

means that location `/pages/online.php` could not be accessed because of lacking permissions. If the file is supposed to be a PHP script, it should be readable (but highly probably not writable) by the web server process.

In addition, the server tried to use custom error page for the HTTP 500 internal server error situation but the server was incorrectly configured and displaying the custom error page failed as a result. (Error message hints about `ErrorDocument` configuration directive which makes this server almost certainly an Apache server.)

To fix the first error, you may need to change access bits for the script and to fix the second error, you must check where Apache ErrorDocument configuration points to. Perhaps there's a typo in the configuration or some file is missing?